# Python JSON dump / append to .txt with each variable on new line

Tags: python, json, append, newline, dump

My code creates a dictionary, which is then stored in a variable.
I want to write each dictionary to a JSON file, but I want each dictionary to be on a new line.

My dictionary:

```
hostDict = {"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": {"sub_key1": "sub_val2", "sub_key2": "sub_val2", "sub_key3": "sub_val3"}, "key4": "val4"}
```

Part of my code:

```
g = open('data.txt', 'a')
with g as outfile:
  json.dump(hostDict, outfile)
```

This appends each dictionary to 'data.txt' but it does so inline. I want each dictionary entry to be on new line. 
Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 165):

Your question is a little unclear. If you're generating `hostDict` in a loop:

```
with open('data.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    for hostDict in ....:
        json.dump(hostDict, outfile)
        outfile.write('\n')
```

If you mean you want each variable within `hostDict` to be on a new line:

```
with open('data.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(hostDict, outfile, indent=2)
```

When the `indent` keyword argument is set it automatically adds newlines.

Comment: This did not seem to work for me; the problem disappeared after I stopped using `json.dump` or `json.dumps` on empty/nonexistent objects.

Comment: 'json.dump(hostDict, outfile, indent=2)' this worked for me. thanks

Comment: Since you are working with JSON you may want to add a comma separator before the newline character: `outfile.write(',\n')`

Answer (score 19):

To avoid confusion, paraphrasing both question and answer. I am assuming that user who posted this question wanted to save dictionary type object in JSON file format but when the user used `json.dump`, this method dumped all its content in one line. Instead, he wanted to record each dictionary entry on a new line. To achieve this use:

```
with g as outfile:
  json.dump(hostDict, outfile,indent=2)
```

Using `indent = 2` helped me to dump each dictionary entry on a new line. Thank you @agf. Rewriting this answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: This is pretty clearly not what the user is asking about, he's asking about storing multiple dicts in a [JSONL format](https://jsonlines.org/). But it's probably helpful for other people coming to this question.