# Add break line after each file merge

Tags: python

I have a lot of JSON files like the following:

E.g.

`1.json`

```
{"name": "one", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
```

`test.json`

```
{"name": "test", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
```

`two.json`

```
{"name": "two", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}

...
```

I want to merge them all in one JSON file like:

`merge_json.json`

```
{"name": "one", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""},
{"name": "test", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""},
{"name": "two", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
```

I have the following code:

```
import json
import glob

result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "r") as infile:
        try:
            result.append(json.load(infile))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f,e)
result = '\n'.join(result)

with open("merged.json", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

I can merge all files, but everything are in a one line how can I add break-line, after adding each file:

instead of:

```
{"name": "one", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""},{"name": "test", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""},{"name": "two", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
```

Have them like:

`merge_json.json`

```
{"name": "one", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""},
{"name": "test", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""},
{"name": "two", "description": "testDescription...", "comment": ""}
```

Appreciated for any help.

Comment: probably pretty printing should do it:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html you will have to figure out the exact combination of parameters on your own

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python JSON dump / append to .txt with each variable on new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055117/python-json-dump-append-to-txt-with-each-variable-on-new-line)

Comment: outfile.write(result)

Comment: infile.read() might also be enough to get the job done without parsing the json just to write is back to a file

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
for f in glob.glob("*.json"):
    with open(f, "r") as infile:
        try:
            result.append(json.load(infile))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f,e)

with open("merged.json", "a", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    for i in result:
        json.dump(i, outfile)
        outfile.write('\n')
```