# Dump each element of list on new line (Python & JSON)

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, dump

I have a list of dictionaries of the form:

```
mylist = [{'name': 'Johnny', 'surname': 'Cashew'}, {'name': 'Abraham', 'surname': 'Linfield'}]
```

and I am trying to dump that to a json this way:

```
with open('myfile.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(mylist, f)
```

but then the entire list is on one line in the json file, making it hardly readable (my list is in reality very long). Is there a way to dump each element of my list on a new line? I have seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055117/python-json-dump-append-to-txt-with-each-variable-on-new-line) that suggests using `indent` in this way:

```
with open('myfile.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(mylist, f, indent=2)
```

but then I get each element within the dictionaries on a new line, like that:

```
[
  {
    'name': 'Johnny',
    'surname: 'Cashew'
  },
  {
    'name': 'Abraham',
    'surname: 'Linfield'
  }
]
```

whereas what I am hoping to obtain is something like that:

```
[
  {'name': 'Johnny', 'surname': 'Cashew'},
  {'name': 'Abraham', 'surname': 'Linfield'}
]
```

Would someone have a hint? Many thanks!

Comment: That's the only configuration of the indents that the built-in JSON library allows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a dirty way  of doing it but it works for me

```py
import json

my_list = [{'name': 'John', 'surname': 'Doe'}, {'name': 'Jane', 'surname': 'Doe'}]
with open('names.json','w') as f:
    f.write('[\n')
    for d in my_list:
        #dumps() instead of dump() so that we can write it like a normal str
        f.write(json.dumps(d)) 
        if d == my_list[-1]:
            f.write("\n")
            break
        f.write(",\n")

    f.write(']')
```